# what should be in added in the manifestfor The method getSupportActionBar() works?

Tags: android

In [android dev tutorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) they explained when I click the icon on the left , it will throw me the "main page" with the below code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and I knew that I need to add for the class ActionBarActivity.
but still I am not able to go back to the main page
maybe problem with manifest.

Display.java

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_main);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.sqlfirst.Display"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:parentActivityName="com.example.sqlfirst.Display.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.sqlfirst.Display.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

why its not going to main page?
Note that my main page is : MainActivity.java

Comment: This is useless code actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); you enable it in your manifest by providing a parent activity

Comment: @BojanKseneman the setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); to make the "arrow" visible. what about my manifest what is wrong in it ?

Comment: The arrow should be visible without you enabling it, because you enabled it in your manifest by assigning a parent activity to the activity. I have never manually enabled it, but it is always there. There does not seem to be anything wrong, but double check that the name "com.example.sqlfirst.Display.MainActivity" is okay

Comment: @BojanKseneman the path is correct, so the only thing to do is to add android:value="com.example.sqlfirst.Display.MainActivity" ? shouldnt I check something else ?

Comment: I meant that you should check if the path is correct, but apparently you are saying that it is. I don't know what else could be wrong, sorry.

Comment: @BojanKseneman well thanks for your help man. I guess later on ill figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

adds a left-facing caret alongside the app icon and enables it as an action button such that when the user presses it, your activity receives a call to onOptionsItemSelected(). The ID for the action is android.R.id.home.

You should override onOptionsItemSelected and use NavUtils

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

More details at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp